# implementing binary search tree in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Functions in scheme/racket.
Working on a few functions using a binary search tree. I have already defined helper functions to be:

```
;; returns value of node
(define (value node)
    (if (null? node) '()
        (car node)))

;; returns left subtree of node
(define (left node)
    (if (null? node) '()
    (cadr node)))

;; returns right subtree of node
(define (right node)
    (if (null? node) '()
    (caddr node)))
```

and I am trying to write a function `size` that takes a tree as a parameter and returns the number of non-null nodes in the given tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're very close. Try this (untested):

```
(define (size tree)
  (if (null? tree) 0
      (+ 1 (size (left tree)) (size (right tree)))))
```

Though, personally, I would much rather prefer to use `#f` as the null value, rather than `'()`. In that case, use `not` instead of `null?` in the first line.

Comment: That is indeed very similar in style. Instead of counting, you are trying to see if the current value is what you're looking for, `or` the left branch `contains` that value, `or` if the right branch `contains` that value. Makes sense? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative!!
You could have used structs, which would reduce the work of writing the three functions...

```
(struct node (val left right) #:transparent)
(struct null-tree ())
```

and directly write the above function using in-built functions for a struct, i.e. a predicate and parameter accessors.

```
(define (size tree)
  (if (null-tree? tree) 0
    (+ 1 (size (left tree)) (size (right tree)))))
```